# Getting vector output segmentation algorithms to work in QGIS

Tags: qgis, orfeo-toolbox, image-segmentation

I am using QGIS 2.0.

I'm trying to run the Watershed Segmentation algorithm, specifically, but I have been receiving the same error message using any of the available segmentation algorithms. I'm new to QGIS and have been running it in OSX 10.9.

The error message I receive says:

> Oooops! The following output layers could not be open
>   Output vector file: /var/folders/mq/01l7wc357319d3bxlsfp8n840000gn/T/processing/606c5f7baef84d2c9d91b5fc023a5947/-mode vector -mode.vector.out.shp
>   The above files could not be opened, which probably indicates that they were not correctly produced by the executed algorithm
>   Checking the log information might help you see why those layers were not created as expected

After checking the log, the OTB execution console output says:

> OTB execution console output
>   Segmentation -filter watershed -in /Volumes/New Volume/Thesis/soterra_LCmap/soterra_mosaic -filter.watershed.threshold 0.01 -filter.watershed.level 0.1 -mode.vector.inmask /Volumes/New Volume/hancockseg/hancockrst/hancockmask.shp -mode.vector.stitch true -mode.vector.minsize 1 -mode.vector.simplify 0 -mode.vector.layername layer -mode.vector.tilesize 1024 -mode.vector.startlabel 1 -mode.vector.outmode ulco -mode vector -mode.vector.out /var/folders/mq/01l7wc357319d3bxlsfp8n840000gn/T/processing/606c5f7baef84d2c9d91b5fc023a5947/-mode vector -mode.vector.out.shp
>
> ERROR: option -mode.vector.out.shp does not exist in the application.

How can I overcome this issue?

As I said, I'm new to QGIS and don't have any experience with open source GIS/RS software in general. My experience has mostly been with ESRI, ERDAS, and IDRISI. I'm very interested in performing some basic segmentation and classification but with a very specific goal in mind which I doubt I could accomplish using the Semi-Automatic Classification Plugin. I'm tempted to give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that there is a bug in Sextante. The command line build regarding user defined parameters is not construct properly. The problem is for the vector data output name.

```
mode vector -mode.vector.out /var/folders/mq/01l7wc357319d3bxlsfp8n840000gn/T/processing/606c5f7baef84d2c9d91b5fc023a5947/-mode vector -mode.vector.out.shp
```

This parameter is defined twice (-mode vector).

The application try to create a shapefile

```
/var/folders/mq/01l7wc357319d3bxlsfp8n840000gn/T/processing/606c5f7baef84d2c9d91b5fc023a5947/-mode vector
```

which is not.

You should report this issue on the QGIS/sextante bugtracker:

https://hub.qgis.org/projects/sextante/issues

Comment: Does it help to specify the output file directly?